# Hive query compare timestamp with unix_timestamp() and received error:ParseException missing ' at '>' near '<EOF>'

Tags: hive

I try to get the data in the past 3 second by compare the `_timestamp` and `unix_timestamp()` but got the error:

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 16:15 missing ' at '>' near ''
line 17:16 missing ' at '<' near ''

```
select myInfo
from my_table
where _timestamp > unix_timestamp() * 1000 - 3000
and _timestamp  < unix_timestamp() * 1000
```

_timestamp looks like this "1674169604292" and it is epoch time in millisecond format. I know `unix_timestamp()` gives you epoch time in second format, that is why * 1000.

[image]

I have no clue what is missing based on the error message.
Can anyone share some insight? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose `_timestamp` with backtick(`). Its not an issue with epoch timestamp.
Use below SQL -

```
select myInfo
from my_table
where `_timestamp` > unix_timestamp() * 1000 - 3000
and `_timestamp`  < unix_timestamp() * 1000
```

[image]